# Library production build failed on angular 11 with: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, angular-ivy

I am trying to build my lib with --prod so i can publish it.

I am getting following error:

**Directive SelectableRow, Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.**

mycomponent.ts

```
 <p-table [value]="values"
             selectionMode="single">

      <ng-template pTemplate="body"
                   let-data>
        <tr [pSelectableRow]="data"> ---> HERE IS THE ERROR!!!
...
```

According to primeng this should be fine.
Primeng example:

```
<p-table [value]="products" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedProduct1" dataKey="code">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-product>
        <tr [pSelectableRow]="product">
            <td>{{product.code}}</td>
            <td>{{product.name}}</td>
            <td>{{product.category}}</td>
            <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

THX!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you are still interested by another way to solve your issue which will allow you to keep enableIvy option to false but here it is :

I was developing an angular library containing the primeng table with the directive pSelectableRow  extacly like you and when I move to angular 11 I start to get the same error than you and the solution for me was in the

```
angularCompilerOptions:
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    //"fullTemplateTypeCheck": true, <= The error was caused by that option
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true,
    "flatModuleId": "AUTOGENERATED",
    "flatModuleOutFile": "AUTOGENERATED"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded to Angular 11 and am having the same problem, with code that worked perfectly before.

First, it should be [pSelectableRow]="rowData", I think.

Second, this error occurs only for me the first time the program is compiled. If I make a change in a source file (add a space and save) and the program is compiled again once the change is detected, the error goes away.

EDIT: finally, I enabled Ivy and the problem went away. Don't ask me to explain!

in tsconfig.app.json:

"angularCompilerOptions": {
"enableIvy": true
}